# 'Tips for searching' dialog takes some time to load

Tags: bug, search

On clicking the search field, the searching tips dialog appear. However, it doesn't appear immediately, it takes some time.

[image]

It can be noticed that the dialog is empty for like < 500 ms and then gets populated.
Once clicked, it can't be reproduced unless the page is refreshed.

<sub>Chrome Version 76

Windows 10 *(64 bit)*</sub>

Comment: When I look at my network request log, I see that the dialog is loaded from https://meta.stackexchange.com/search/hints. So that's why it takes some time to load. It is probably cached after the first time and therefore loads immediately.